# Localized URLs in Play 2.0?

Tags: url, seo, playframework-2.0

Yesterday we had a Play 2.0 presentation at our local [JUG](http://www.finjug.org) but we couldn't figure out whether it is possible to have localized URLs (for SEO purposes).

For example /help, /hilfe etc should point to the same controller but the template should be rendered with different language content.

Is there any way to do this in Play 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

I like your question, because it was creative at least for me :) Check this approach it works for me:

**`conf/routes`**:

```
GET     /help     controllers.Application.helpIndex(lang = "en")
GET     /hilfe    controllers.Application.helpIndex(lang = "de")

GET     /help/:id     controllers.Application.helpTopic(lang = "en", id: Long)
GET     /hilfe/:id    controllers.Application.helpTopic(lang = "de", id: Long)
```

**`controllers/Application.java`**:

```
public static Result helpIndex(String lang) {
    return ok("Display help's index in " + lang.toUpperCase());
}

public static Result helpTopic(String lang, Long id) {
    return ok("Display details of help topic no " + id + " in " + lang.toUpperCase());
}
```

**`views/someView.scala.html`**:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.helpIndex("en")">Help index</a><br/>
<a href="@routes.Application.helpIndex("de")">Hilfe index</a><br/>

<a href="@routes.Application.helpTopic("en", 12)">Help topic no 12</a><br/>
<a href="@routes.Application.helpTopic("de", 12)">Hilfe topic no 12</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

(This is different approach than in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10449571/1066240), therefore added as separate one)

You can also create some kind of `mapping table` in DB where you can store full paths to records with different params:

```
urlpath              record_id    lang
/help/some-topic     12           en
/hilfe/ein-topic     12           de
```

than in `conf/routes` file you need to use rule allowing you to use `Dynamic parts spanning several /` (see [routing doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaRouting)) ie:

```
GET    /:topic    controller.Application.customDbRouter(topic:String)
```

You can also mix both - standard routing mechanismus with custom one by placing above rule at the end of your `conf/routes` file if no 'static' rule will be available, then it will try to find it in mapping table or will return `notFound()` Result.

Answer (score 1):

You use from [GlobalSettings.onHandlerNotFound()](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/java/play/GlobalSettings.html#onHandlerNotFound%28java.lang.String%29) and check if the is a translated version of the url. Then you can make a redirect. However this ends with urls in default language.

More cleaner would be to use the [GlobalSettings.onRouteRequest](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/java/play/GlobalSettings.html#onRouteRequest%28play.api.mvc.RequestHeader%29) where you can implement your own logic to get the handler.

Furthermore you can create your own router. There was a discussion about it at [google-groups](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/3_qIOPB4Z_I/discussion) with a [scala solution](https://gist.github.com/1866044).

Answer (score 0):

It was possible in Play 1.2.x, not in 2.x as far as I know. I mean, it's not possible without duplicating the mappings in your file, adding one for EN, one for DE, etc.

A simpler alternative for SEO may be to "fake" the urls in your Sitemaps file.

So your Routes file has

```
GET  /action/:param/:seo-string   Controller.methodAction(param)
```

so `seo-string` will be ignored in processing, and you generate several links on your Sitemaps file:

```
/action/1/english-text
/action/1/german-text
```

This would set the search engines. For users, so they see the url in the right language, you could change the URL using HTML 5 history.

It's extra work, but if you really want it...